# If $T$ is injective then there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $||Tx||\geq \alpha||x||$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Is this proof correct? I'm proving that if $T$ is a linear operator whose is injective then exist $\alpha>0$ such that $$||Tx||\geq\alpha||x||$$ for all $x$. 
By contrapositive. Assume that for all $$\alpha>0$$ there is a $x$ such that $||Tx||<\alpha||x||$. In particular for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $x_n$ such that 
$$||T(x_n)||<\frac{1}{n}||x_n||.$$ Suppose (without lose of generally) that $||x_n||=1$ (in other case normalize the vector $x_n$). 
Now since $x_n$ is a bounded sequence, by the Bolzano-Weirstrass there is a subsequence that converges. Let $$x_{n_k}\to x$$ then $x\neq 0$ because $||x_{n_k}||=1$. Now for any $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ large as necessary we have, $$||T(x)||\leq ||T(x-x_n)||+||T(x_n)||<\epsilon+\frac{1}{n}$$ therefore $||T(x)||<\epsilon\Rightarrow T(x)=0$ since $x\neq 0$, $T$ cannot be injective.
Any comment, sugest or new solution are welcome!!

Comment: Are you working in finite dimensions?

Comment: Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R[X]$ of polynomials, $\|f\|=\sqrt{\sum a_i^2}$ if $f(X)=\sum a_iX^i$ and let $T$ be formal integration. Then $\|T(X^n)\|=\|\frac1{n+1}X^{n+1}\|=\frac1{n+1}$!

Comment: Is finite-dimensional case. $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. Still the proof is wrong?

Comment: For finite-dimensional spaces, it's okay, since those are locally compact. In particular, the sphere $\lVert x\rVert = 1$ is compact, so you can extract a convergent subsequence. You wouldn't be able to do that in infinite-dimensional spaces, and there the conclusion need not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not true. The typical example is the operator that maps the canonical basis $\{e_n\}$ as
$$
T:e_n\mapsto\,\frac1n\,e_n. 
$$
This map is injective, but $\|Te_n\|=\frac1n$, so no $\alpha$ exists.

Note that if you follow your argument with this example in mind, you see that you are using Bolzano Weiertrass, which requires your sequence to be inside a compact set.

**The finite-dimensional case:**

If you want to do your proof in the finite-dimensional case then it works, but it can be done much more easily by noting that if $T$ is injective then it is invertible onto its image, then the inverse is a bounded map (every linear map is bounded in finite-dimension) and so you can take $\alpha=\|T^{-1}\|^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes i'm working in finite dimensional case. $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: So how can i fix the proof?. I want to try both ideas.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, your proof is correct. I was just mentioning that there is a simpler argument.

Comment: Thanks. With respect to the $\alpha=||T^{-1}||^{-1}$ why $$||T(x)||\geq ||x||/\alpha?.$$

Comment: No, $\|Tx\|\geq\alpha\|x\|$. Because $$\|x\|=\|T^{-1}Tx\|\leq\|T^{-1}\|\,\|Tx\|.$$

Comment: OH!! Thanks your solution is very nice and easy.

Comment: You're very welcome.